# How do you create a subclass so that the parameters are of the subclass type in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have the abstract parent class Animal:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract <T extends Animal> T copyAnimal(T animal);
}
```

I then want to create a subclass Duck but to override the copyAnimal I want to use Duck as the parameters such that:

```
public class Duck extends Animal
{
    @Override
    public Duck copyAnimal(Duck duck)
    {
        return copyOfDuck;
    }
}
```

This of course gives me a compiler error saying that the method is not overridden. That being said how can I adjust this code so that I don't have to pass Animal to the copyAnimal() method to save casting, etc. since it looks ugly and would require additional runtime checks. Or is it even possible? And if not then what's the most elegant solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public abstract class Animal<A extends Animal<A>>
{
    public abstract A copyAnimal(A animal);
}
```

Then:

```
public class Duck extends Animal<Duck>
```

Note that you can't constrain it to be the "self" type (e.g. it could be `Duck extends Animal<Pig>`); you just have to only declare the classes you want to declare.

Comment: Thank you, that's awesome!! I will accept your answer in 11 minutes (when SO lets me).

Comment: Talk about an ugly duckling. :)

Comment: On a side note do you know of any good reference material, tutorials, books, etc. on this? I would love to improve my knowledge on generic polymorphism.

Comment: [Angelika Langer's reference](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) is considered the most thorough, I believe.

Comment: On a side not is it possible to extend and extended class? For example: class Mallard extends Duck<Mallard>

Comment: I posted a new question for subclassing the subclass at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457750/how-do-you-create-multiple-levels-of-subclasses-so-that-the-parameters-are-of-th