# How do you create multiple levels of subclasses so that the parameters are of the subclasses?

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

Following this [StackOverFlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457487/how-do-you-create-a-subclass-so-that-the-parameters-are-of-the-subclass-type-in) let's say I want to expand to another level of subclasses, say Mallards, how do I do it?

```
public abstract class Animal <A extends Animal<A>>
{
    public abstract A copyAnimal(A animal);
}

public class Duck extends Animal<Duck>
{
    @Override
    public Duck copyAnimal(Duck duck)
    {
        return copyOfDuck;
    }
}

class Mallard extends Duck<Mallard>
{
    public Mallard copyAnimal(Mallard mallard)
    {
        return copyOfMallard;
    }   
}
```

Everything works great for the Duck subclass but it fails for the Mallard sub-subclass. How can I set this up with an undetermined number of subclasses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just keep going with the type variables:

```
class Duck<D extends Duck<D>> extends Animal<D> {}
```

then

```
class Mallard extends Duck<Mallard> {}
```

Yep, it's pretty messy!

I have most often seen this pattern used with a builder of a classes that is extended to create a builders of a subclass. It makes a total mess of the code, and in my opinion is best avoided.

---

An example of how to use it:

```
abstract class Animal<A extends Animal<A>> {
  abstract A copyAnimal(A animal);
}

class Duck<D extends Duck<D>> extends Animal<D> {
  void quack() {}

  D copyAnimal(D duck) {
    duck.quack();
    return duck;
  }
}

class Mallard extends Duck<Mallard> {
  Mallard copyAnimal(Mallard duck) {
    duck.quack();
    return duck;
  }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/fJtNx3) (does nothing; merely demonstrates compilation)

Comment: @rgettman aww, I was going for yet another bizarre genetic hybrid.

Comment: But then then also means you can do public Duck copyAnimal(Duck duck) on the duck level? It means you need to do public D copyAnimal(D duck) Is that right ?

Comment: The reason for the subclass is because the parent class has a few methods that they all share. Then the Mallard is 90% the same as the Duck class so to avoid duplication and make it easier to read it's cleaner to subclass it.

Comment: Also does this mean that in copyAnimal I can't reference any of Duck's method such as duck.getQuackNoise() ?

Comment: In other words would you mind including the code for the copyAnimal method in Duck, using one of duck's methods. I can't seem to get that to work... It's even saying I can't return a duck.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier see example added.

Comment: Thank you, I had a stupid bug. I did class Duck<D extends Animal<D>> ... instead of extends Duck. That makes more sense. Thank you again!!